# Unable to read excel files from set of folder using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read excel files from a folder using xlrd but an extra file is being created with extension  `".~.Lock.example1.xlsm"` which is eventually giving `xlrderror :unsupported file format`.When i try to read individual files everythig is fine.
my folder files are: `example1.xlsm, example2.xlsm, example3.xlsm`

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os,sys
import xlsxwriter
path=r"D:\Users\SS\Documents\excel_files"
os.chdir(path)
folders=os.listdir(path) #list of all folders with excel files
for f in folders:
     df=pd.DataFrame()
     path1=os.path.abspath(f)
     files=os.listdir(path1) #list of excel files of specific folder
     os.chdir(path1)
     for f1 in files:
        print(f1)
        data=pd.read_excel(f1,None)  #Lock file is causing error here
```

Comment: why not use` pd.read_excel`?

Comment: @Mohit is right, it's better to use the inbuilt pandas excel loader. But with your specific problem regarding windows temporary/backup files, to fix it cheaply you can simply ignore the file if the filename starts with a '~' or '.'.

Comment: or, you can add a `try...except` block inside the loop

Comment: Thanks guys.The issue is I am  reading the excel files as dataframe with some  specific sheets .So that lock file cant be read which is causing error.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work this out is to add these into your code so it only read excel files, instead of every files in the folder.

```
for f1 in files:
    if f1.endswith(".xlsx"):
        #Do something with f1
```

Also, I find `os.walk(path)` very useful if you want to find all the files under a given folder.
So altogether, we can do something like this:

```
path = 'D:\Users\SS\Documents\excel_files'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            #Do something with file
```

Comment: Thanks kelvin.That worked but I couldnt figure out why this even occuring

Comment: oh, it is very likely that this event happens when the file is being locked for editing (by yourself or by another user that has access to this file)